# Stepping down as Moderator

Tags: discussion, moderators

Over the last years I’ve become more and more inactive in the community. When I joined some seven years ago I’ve just finished school as BSc with major in Information Architecture. I had all the time in the world, and really loved being here. I still do, but in my current roles at work, time has become more and more limited. I still love the questions and answers, and we have the most solid community on the Stack Exchange network.

This leads me to actively step down as moderator. But I won’t leave the community. I’ll stick around and continue to ask and answer questions as they come along.

Sincerely,
Benny Skogberg

Answer (score 4):

Sorry to see you step down. Hope you stick around, you've got a wealth of great knowledge and experience to share. All the best.

Comment: Thanks Jon! I will. I'll be here as often as I can, and hopefully I can increase my activity within a year or so. Se you!

Answer (score 4):

The current moderators for UXSE (apart from myself) have been around ever since I posted my first Question/Answer, so it is sad to see one of the moderators depart.

However, I hope that others will also step in to fill in the void, and that as one chapter closes another one will unfold :)

Comment: Definitely so, and I for one think you do a really good job moderating for the time beeing. Keep up the spirit - you have my support :)

Comment: @4rchit3ct thanks for the kind comments :) It is interesting to find your touches throughout UXSE and they have been an invaluable part of my learning process as well!

Answer (score 4):

I feel you Benny, that's also what's preventing me from participating in the elections for the past few years, although a large part of me wants to :). Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! Signing up for a Solutions Architect role is a little more demanding than a "regular" SharePoint Consultant job. However - I finally get to use the experiences of this site in my new role :)

Answer (score 3):

You're one of the people that helped make ux.se work through its growing pains :) Thanks for all your effort. I'm sorry you're stepping down, but also glad that you have other great things to do with your time!
Rog.

Comment: Thanks for those kind words, Rog! I'll stick around and will hopefully increase my activity within a year or so. After all - current position is closer to UX than any other job I've had. The irony :)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your service to the community!

Comment: Thanks Rob! Appreciated!